# Can an 80386 run modern x86 executables?

Tags: x86, i386

If I compile a 32 bit executable to run on my modern i5, can I run it on an 80386? Assume I'm using the same operating system for both CPUs.

Comment: Only if your compiler sticks to 386 instructions. There should be a flag for that.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, most modern compilers default to assuming PPro new instructions like [`cmov`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmovcc) and `fcomi`.  Also 486 instructions like [`bswap`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bswap).  Depending on your compiler config, it might even default to using SSE2 instructions in 32-bit mode.  (Pentium 4 / Pentium-M / AMD K8 from the early 2000s.)

If you want to override that default, e.g. for GCC or clang, **you can use `-m32 -march=i386`**
For example:

```
int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > 3) ? 4 : b;
}
```

GCC -O3 -m32 (with a standard / default config [on Godolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEINIADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/qRJKY4CIWGRLDFx0naYDmlCBEzEBBk%2Bfly2mPb5DDV1BIUR0bF6CrX1jVktQ929xaUSAJS2qF7EyOwcoQQA1PyoEOsbTKQbe1GzJhoAgiYA7FYXG/cbxJgESwwbEEwbJgDM2Bvfsy%2B3wAYhtJBsQBsoj9bpcrgARDjzWicACsvD8HC0pFQnDc1msGwUi2WmC%2BZm%2BPFIBE0SPmAGsQN9JAA6ZlXABsZlRHO%2B3wAnN8zFd9JxJLwWBINBpSJjsbiOLwFCAZTSsUjSHBYEg0CwEnRYuRKLr9fQ4sAuFwAjRaARYsqIFFaaQoqE6gBPThU3VsQQAeQYtE96tIWBYhmA4hD%2BCeVQAbphlSHMKpKl47V7eOs2s7aHgosQPR4sM6CMQ8JLuBqqAZgAoAGp4TAAdz9CUYmZkghEYnYUi78iUamduhaBiMKAJln0%2BeVkHmqASHSTAFpw8sED94XhvgAODkbFd%2B76HgDqYloh5YQqVbUqHRcDHcniaEgCwVCfRKA13OWSqQEUZmgCXIAIYKZ%2BjiX8KiqAQuhGF8xladpqmGHpP2mAZxjQoDBjQiDvziLh5mJJYVj0MtMFWHhkTRDFnQVVR9xXDlwWAZBkA2S0WTMd58UsaxDlwQgSHJSlDg8PUDWIMTiN4NUtFmBkmTMNkuH5DRJC4DQhSuPl%2BV3VFRQ4cVSElbSZTlXgFSVFVqVpeYtUQFBUCks0jQgE1pJAC0rT4Og7WIB0nRDV1mGIYNvVc30CADINnTDCMo2xGN7zwBMk2xFM0wzKtyEEHMQzzAsiwwVZsTLCtM3mGsmDrRsWzbDs8v4btRHEftWsHFR1BDXQAnHYwpxsYq5wgBclzSVdr14o8TxXc9aFoW8UOcCBXFwvyPyKSCQCM0COk2kD/w6AiZiMmCOnghpEOaZC0rg/CMN27Duk22wnp2wi5gWMi%2B2pJ5qI1FEOHRWUGM4JiORYtiOK4rgeL44ahPwIgZPMcSNkk01YjEsxZnkhzlL5Nk%2BTJ8nyeM0yrJxThbNVInjLMeiQxs%2Bz1SU0gEyCtJ4iAA%3D%3D%3D)) compiles to

```
foo(int, int):
        cmp     DWORD PTR [esp+4], 3
        mov     eax, 4
        cmovle  eax, DWORD PTR [esp+8]
        ret
```

vs. with `-march=i386 -O3 -Wall -m32`

```
foo(int, int):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+8]
        cmp     DWORD PTR [esp+4], 3
        jg      .L4
        ret
.L4:
        mov     eax, 4
        ret
```